# Vue3-easy-data-table installation for nuxt 3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm trying to install [vue3-easy-data-table](https://hc200ok.github.io/vue3-easy-data-table-doc/) for my nuxt 3 project. However the [documentation](https://hc200ok.github.io/vue3-easy-data-table-doc/getting-started/es-module.html) doesn't really have a guide on nuxt 3 installation. Does anyone know how to install it? The following steps are what I did for installation but it doesn't work.

Step 1 : `npm install vue3-easy-data-table`
Step 2 : create a file called `easy-data-table.js` in the plugins directory.
Step 3 : added this piece of code in `easy-data-table.js`

```
import "vue3-easy-data-table/dist/style.css";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(Vue3EasyDataTable);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The configuration would be something like this.

`~/plugins/easy-data-table.ts`

```js
import Vue3EasyDataTable from 'vue3-easy-data-table'
import 'vue3-easy-data-table/dist/style.css'

export default defineNuxtPlugin( ( nuxtApp ) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.component( 'EasyDataTable', Vue3EasyDataTable )
} )
```

Usage with basic example.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <EasyDataTable
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import type { Header, Item } from "vue3-easy-data-table"

const headers: Header[] = [
  { text: "PLAYER", value: "player" },
  { text: "TEAM", value: "team" },
  { text: "NUMBER", value: "number" },
  { text: "POSITION", value: "position" },
  { text: "HEIGHT", value: "indicator.height" },
  { text: "WEIGHT (lbs)", value: "indicator.weight", sortable: true },
  { text: "LAST ATTENDED", value: "lastAttended", width: 200 },
  { text: "COUNTRY", value: "country" },
]

const items: Item[] = [
  { player: "Stephen Curry", team: "GSW", number: 30, position: 'G', indicator: { "height": '6-2', "weight": 185 }, lastAttended: "Davidson", country: "USA" },
  { player: "Lebron James", team: "LAL", number: 6, position: 'F', indicator: { "height": '6-9', "weight": 250 }, lastAttended: "St. Vincent-St. Mary HS (OH)", country: "USA" },
  { player: "Kevin Durant", team: "BKN", number: 7, position: 'F', indicator: { "height": '6-10', "weight": 240 }, lastAttended: "Texas-Austin", country: "USA" },
  { player: "Giannis Antetokounmpo", team: "MIL", number: 34, position: 'F', indicator: { "height": '6-11', "weight": 242 }, lastAttended: "Filathlitikos", country: "Greece" },
]
</script>
```

Expected output

[image]

Hope that helps!